# YouTube embed/API player redirects from HTTP -> HTTPS, API is inaccessible

Tags: youtube-api

When I attempt to load an embedded video onto my page, using the following:

```
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/BzC135ql_wA?version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1"></embed>
```

the request is automatically redirected from HTTP to HTTPS- as a result the API is inaccessible, because of browser security limitations.

This appears to be related to my Google account, as it doesn't redirect if I try from an incognito window. However, this worries me- some users of my site won't be able to use the page as I intended, and as far as I can see I will have no way of knowing.

Is there any way to force HTTP, or anything else I can do here, short of hosting my own site on HTTPS?

Comment: Can you try embed src="//www.youtube.com"? This'll switch HTTP or HTTPS depending on whatever protocol is being used to request the page. This is describe here: http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: It still redirects. But it turns out that the API is still accessible, despite the warning on the browser console. So I'm fine for now, but still curious if I can control/know about it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of browser extensions that automatically translate http:// URLs into https:// for a specific set of domains. I'd imagine that you're using one such extension, which would explain why you don't see that behavior in an Incognito window. I can't tell you which extension you might be using—I know that HTTPS Everywhere is popular on Firefox, but not sure which are commonly used on Chrome—but take a look at `chrome://extensions/` for any likely culprits.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this issue when using HTTPS Everywhere in Chrome.